# Skype video feeds not showing

Tags: video, skype, webcam

Skype video feeds show up as a green box. The webcam is a Microsoft lifecam but that should'nt matter because the camera works in cheese webcam both and the person i am skyping can see me. I thought it might have something to do with video codecs or something. Help?[image]

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using?  Which Skype version is installed?  What video card do you have?  Are your video drivers up to date?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04
skype:i386 4.2.0.11-1
Video is Intel® Haswell Desktop (HD 4600)
I believe it uses the mesa driver which should be updated with the kernel.
could it be that skype is i386 on a x64 os? maybe because of the lack of i386 codecs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. VLC did not work either.

I have updated Intel drivers and it worked for me :)

[Link to Intel driver updater](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2)